# Where does a template(.t) file belong if i already have a header?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, header, format

I should be able get these 4 files to compile without changing anything. I first thought the .t file was a header file but then it makes it a (.h) file, and i already have "arrayi.h" for that? Can anyone help me format them correctly? Please and thank you.

I have this 4 files to put in 1 project: .h / .t / .cpp / client driver.cpp.

.t below

```
// File name         : arrayi.t

#ifndef ARRAYI_T_
#define ARRAYI_T_


#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
using namespace::std;


// Default constructor for class Array
template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array(int arraySize)
{
    cout << "calling the constructor \n";
}

// Overloaded output operator for class Array
template<typename T>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Array<T> &a)
{

  int i;
  output << "{ ";

  for (i = 0; i < a.size; i++)
    {
      output << a.ptr[i] << ' ';

      if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
        output << "}" << endl;
    }  //end for

  if (i % 10 != 0)
    output << "}" << endl;

  return output;   // enables cout << x << y;
}



#endif
```

.h below

```
// File name         : arrayi.h


#ifndef ARRAYI_H_
#define ARRAYI_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
using namespace::std;


template<typename T> class Array;
template<typename T>
ostream &operator<< (ostream& output, const Array<T> &a);


template<typename T>
class Array
{
    friend ostream &operator<< <>(ostream &output, const Array<T> &a);


public:
    Array(int = 10);    //constructor


  private:

};

#include "arrayi.t"

#endif
```

.cpp below

```
// File name         : arrayi.cpp


#include "arrayi.h"

#include "arrayi.t"
```

client driver.cpp below

```
// File name         : client_driver.cpp


#include<iostream>
using namespace::std;

#include "arrayi.h"
```

Comment: `using namespace ::std` in a header file (or in the `.t` file) [is a big no-no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to include the `.h` file in your `.cpp` files. Then compile the `.cpp` files, but not the `.h` and `.t` files, as translation units.

The `.t` is basically only meant to separate the template implementation into another file. It really belongs into the header file and that is why it is included in the `.h`. Other code need not bother with it at all.